# why doesn't React list onReset event for forms?

Tags: reactjs

React doesn't list `onReset` among the [form events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#form-events).

Regardless, in React 0.14 `onReset` apparently is available for forms and in fact is fed a SyntheticEvent.

E.g. the below code:

```
return React.createElement('form', {
       onSubmit: this.addContact,
       onReset: function(se) {
            console.log('form reset: '+se.constructor.name);
       }}
       , ....
```

prints:

```
form reset: SyntheticEvent
```

on the console.
Is this an omission in the documentation or I am not looking at the right place or misunderstand something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The onReset was added a long time ago in the code (apparently in 0.9: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/83ee3c38a490fc4f5c5179364a7ce9bfc65ed542/docs/_posts/2014-02-20-react-v0.9.md ).

I guess it must be an omission in the documentation. You should submit an issue regarding this point.